# How to get the ORIGINAL logged in user

Tags: vbscript

We have a VBScript that pulls the username from HKCU\Volatile Environment\USERNAME. This is great except when running the script as an admin. Then this value changes to the admin username.

Where/how can I get the ORIGINAL username that was logged in? I can't get it from HKEY_CURRENT_USER because the ADMIN account get swapped in from HKEY_USERS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276361/how-to-get-username-with-vbs may be of some interest

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/301860/692942

Comment: WMI should be able to help here, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34500290/find-user-logged-on-to-a-remote-computer).

Answer (score 0):

I found it.  I KNEW that the registry had to be hiding the last logged in user somewhere!

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\ LastLoggedOnUser = ".\crewr"
```

Pull that string and just

```
replace( returnedRegString, ".\", "" )
```

and you're golden!